# Is there a system environment variable that can reliably distinguish Windows from Linux?

Tags: linux, windows

I develop on Windows and deploy on Linux.  99% of my code works the same on either system, but occasionally I need an `if` statement contingent on the OS.

Is there a system environment variable or variables I can read that indicates the OS?

It would be convenient to read this value rather than have to come up with my own way to distinguish the OS. Without this, I have to keep toggling a value in a config JSON file that my application reads.

If this environment variable idea is a bad one, is there a 3rd option altogether I'm not seeing?

Comment: How do you "develop"? In what environment? In what language?

Comment: I use both R and Python.  They are both able to read system environment variables in a similar way, and I assume most languages have this capability.  Therefore, I prefer to keep this question as generic as far as language, and specific to Windows and Linux and their environment variables.

Comment: Most languages usually defines symbols using the language features itself. For C and C++ it's in the form of preprocessor macros. For Python you can use [the `platform` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#module-platform). And I'm sure R have something specific to itself. So in short, it's not as simple as reading a single environment variable (which can very well give false results).

Comment: You should [edit] the question and add the information about the languages. I also suggest to add details about what specifically you need to do different depending on the OS. There might be library functions or packages to provide an abstraction that would work the same on any OS.